# How can I connect to an Oracle database as SYS using an ADO connection string?

Tags: oracle, ado, connection-string, sysdba

I am trying this:

```
Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sys;Password=pwd;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Data Source=OdbcDataSource;DBA Privilege=SYSDBA
```

But I get the error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
```

I'm using Delphi, but answers in any language are welcome.

***Clarification:
I am able to connect as a normal user.  I run into trouble when I try to connect AS SYSDBA.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't connect as SYSDBA using standard System.Data.OracleClient, as stated by this post : http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=2245591&SiteID=1.

You can do that using ODP .NET (Oracle Data Provider for .NET), or other third parties library. If you're planning to build serious Oracle Application on .NET, I suggest you at least look at ODP.NET

Comment: We moved from ODP.Net to the excellent third party library - DevArt (formerly CoreLAB)'s OraDirect.Net. They let you connect as SYSDBA or SYSOPER (http://www.devart.com/oranet/docs/CoreLab.Oracle~CoreLab.Oracle.OracleConnectionStringBuilder~ConnectMode.html)  :o)

Answer (score 2):

Posting the answer here as this is the top result when looking for an answer for DBA PRIVILEGE connection string

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = ORCL))); User ID=sys; Password=syspassword; DBA PRIVILEGE=SYSDBA
```

Comment: I approved the improvement. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by connecting as a SYS, but there here is a link to sweet repository of [connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com). I hope you can find your answer there.

Comment: as sys = with the user name of "sys".  From sql plus it would be SYS AS SYSDBA.

Answer (score 1):

using [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/oracle.manageddataaccess/),
the connection string for sys as sysdba is:

```
Data Source=myOracleDB;User Id=SYS;Password=SYS;DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;
```

[ref](https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/privileged-connection-sysdba/)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Connection string sample

You must have your Oracle SID defined in your TNSNames file.  Which is the data source.

```
Data Source=oracl;User Id=userID;Password=password;Integrated Security=no
```

If you are using Visual Studios you can add a data source in the Sever Explore and it will give you the connection string.