# How can I connect to an Oracle database as SYSDBA using dbExpress?

Tags: oracle, delphi, dbexpress, ora-01017

I have a Delphi application that connects to an oracle database.

When I try to log in as SYSDBA, I get the error:

```
ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

When I try to log in with a user of "SYS AS SYSDBA", I get the error:

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

**How can I log in as sysdba using a dbExpress connection?**

[See also this related post regarding ADO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179365/how-can-i-connect-to-an-oracle-database-as-sys-using-an-ado-connection-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found nothing specific for special dbexpress driver. But try to add a connection parameter **DBA privilege** with the value **SYSDBA**.

```
Connection.Params.Append('DBA Privilege=SYSDBA');
```

I have no delphi installed to check the concrete syntax of the parameter name. Please try using an underscore instead of the blank.

[This page](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle) shows several connection strings used in certain tools to connect to oracle database.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work- same error messages as before.
Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Specify the user as "Joseph as SYSDBA" instead of Joseph

I found a checklist but not sure whether it is useful or not. Just have a look.

[Checklist](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01017.htm)

Comment: tried that, with this result: "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied" --- using "sys as sysdba"

Answer (score 1):

connect SYS as SYSDBA;

or you can use SYSOPER

the password will be what you specified at installation (same as SYSTEM)

refer:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/users_secure.htm#ADMQS12004